# Java - Return list of specified generic type

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have a list of objects that contains various sub-types:

```
List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<>();
dogList.add(new Poodle())
dogList.add(new Dalmation());
```

I want to search this list and return all instances of a specified class:

```
public <T extends Dog> List<T> getAll(Class<T> dogType){
    List<T> returnObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    for(T obj : dogList){
        if(dogType.instanceOf(obj){
            returnObjects.add(dogType.cast(obj));
        }
    }
    return returnObjects; 
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Poodle> poodleList = getAll(Poodle.class);
```

This is my first proper foray into generics, and things feel like they are getting a bit out of control. Is this a decent way of doing things, or am I missing a more simple/obvious solution?

**Edit**: updated to use instanceOf() and cast() to avoid unchecked cast

Comment: have a look at the keyword `instanceof`

Comment: `for(T obj : dogList)` will not compile: `dogList` cannot be a `List<T>` since it is declared outside of `getAll`. You should replace `T` with `Dog` in the _foreach_.

Comment: BTW this could have been a better fit for [codereview.se]…

Comment: Note that `dogType.instanceOf(obj)` should be `dogType.isInstance(obj)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to declare a return type for the method and check `isAssignableFrom()` on the classes:

```
public <T extends Dog> List<T> getAll(Class<T> dogType){
  List<T> returnObjects = new ArrayList<>();

  for(Dog obj : dogList){ 
    if( dogType.isInstance(obj) ){ //as mentioned in the edit as well as the comments
        returnObjects.add(dogType.cast(obj));
    }
  }
  return returnObjects; 
}
```

That way calling `List<Poodle> poodleList = getAll(Poodle.class);` should return only instances of `Poodle` or subclasses while `getAll(Dog.class)` should return all dogs.

A few notes:

- Assuming `dogList` only contains dogs, you should use the `Dog` type here. Otherwise use the generic type of that array/collection (when in doubt it would be `Object`).
- `isAssignableFrom()` checks whether the left most class is the same as the passed one or a super type, i.e. `Dog.class.isAssignableFrom( Poodle.class )` will be true if `Poodle extends Dog`. If you're only after exact matches use `dogType.equals(obj.getClass())` instead.

**Edit**: a short note on `dogType.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())`: this might result in a NPE if `obj` is null so you'd have to handle that. On the other hand, using `dogType.isInstance(obj)` is easier to read and doesn't suffer from NPE (since `dogType` shouldn't be null). (see @Tunaki's answer as well)

Comment: missing the return type was a typo, have added it in an edit to my post

Comment: I feel like I'm missing the difference between isAssignableFrom and equals - if I use isAssignableFrom, would I also get any subclasses of Poodle, but with equals I would only get Poodle?

Comment: @ms813 yes, let's put it in another way: let's say `MiniaturePoodle extends Poodle`. If you use `equals` you'd only get instances of `Poodle`, if you use `isAssignableFrom` you'd get instances of both `Poodle` and `MiniaturePoodle`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll bear this in mind as I continue developing, I'm not exactly sure which case I want yet!

Comment: You should use `isInstance` instead of `isAssignableFrom` since you are working on instances. It will be much simpler to read and understand. Moreover you can use `dogType.cast(obj)` to avoid the unchecked cast. I think it would be better to change the code than only mentioning it in the edit.

Comment: @ms813 the code in your question is now better than the code in this answer! But that's going to be confusing as answers will be based on your initial code…

Comment: @DidierL I'll change it :)

Comment: Using, if(dogType.isInstance(obj) && dogType==obj.getClass()) will help for the case where we are looking for just Dog class objects(no derived)

Comment: @deadLock in that case `dogType == obj.getClass()` should be sufficient. Just keep in mind that doing so might not make much sense, i.e. if `Dog` was an interface or abstract class there won't be any instances of exactly this type.

Answer (score 9):

Since you mentioned you are using Java 8, you could use the Stream API:

```
public static <T extends Dog> List<T> getAll(Class<T> dogType) {
    return dogList.stream()
                  .filter(dogType::isInstance)
                  .map(dogType::cast)
                  .collect(toList());
}
```

This method will create a `Stream` from the list of dogs, filter them by keeping only those that are an instance of the given class, cast to the given class and finally collect that Stream into a List.

Using `isInstance` means that if you call the method with `Poodle.class`, then all the dogs that are either a `Poodle` or a sub-class of `Poodle` will be kept. If you only want to keep dogs that are `Poodle`, you can use `Class.equals(other)` instead.

Also, note that using the `cast` method, there is no unchecked warning (this method already handles it) and it is safe to do it here since we filtered the correct elements before: no `ClassCastException` can be thrown.

Comment: Oh, yes. I totally forgot about `isInstance()` which would be better than `isAssignableFrom()` here due to NPE prevention. (+1)

Comment: This looks really neat. I haven't read up on the Stream API yet, I'll bump it up my list